# Improved Markov inequality when I have higher moments?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

If I have all the first $n$ moments of a discrete random variable $Z$ defined on the non-negative integers $$\mathbb{E}(Z),\mathbb{E}(Z^2),\dots,\mathbb{E}(Z^n)$$ but desire $P(Z \geq 1)$, Markov's inequality can bound this from above with $\mathbb{E}(Z)$.

Can I do better using the remaining $(n-1)$ moments at my disposal? Are there better bounds on $P(Z \geq 1)$ which are more precise when more moments are incorporated?

Comment: Depends on the distribution. For example if $P(Z=0)=0$ then $Z \geq 1$ a.s. so $EZ\leq EZ^{2}\leq EZ^{3}...$  in which case the best bound is given by $P(Z\geq 1) \leq EZ$.

Comment: $P(Z\geq 1)=P(Z^k\geq 1)\leq EZ^k$. In this way you can use all the first $n$ moments.

Comment: This gives new bounds, but I think the idea is to use the $\inf_{k \geq 0}\mathbb{E}Z^{k}$, which gives something equivalent to the Chernoff bound. The bounds are not necessarily any better, often being optimal for $k=1$.

Answer (score 0):

One can use the factorial moment bound

$$P(Z \geq 1) = 1 - \sum_{i \geq 0} \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}\mathbb{E}\left[\left( Z\right)_i\right]$$
where $\left( Z\right)_i = Z(Z-1)\dots(Z-i+1)$ is the descending factorial.

Comment: One thing, can this work with approximate moments?